# Mockito when().thenReturn() doesn't work in System Under Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I've read all the other topics here, but cannot find the right solution.

I'm testing a controller which calls a service I want to mock.
If within the test I control the result of the `when().thenReturn()` rule, there it works fine.

When I debug and check if the defined rule is VALID and APPLIED within the System Under Test (that is my Controller) then, the rule is not applied at all and it returns a null value instead the one I wanted. Let's go deeper in my code!

Here there is my Controller Method, which is the System Under Test:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> loginUser(@RequestParam(value ="id") String id, @RequestParam(value="password") String pwd){
   try {
      Optional<User> userr = loginService.getUserFromDbAndVerifyPassword(id, pwd);      //verify the presence into the database
      if (userr.isPresent()) {
         User user = userr.get();  
         String jwt = loginService.createJwt(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPermission(), new Date());
         return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).header("jwt", jwt).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.OK.value(),"Success! User logged in." + jwt));
      }
   }catch(UserNotLoggedException e1){ 
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),"Login failed! Wrong credentials. " + e1.toString()));
   }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e2){
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),"Login failed! Encoding permission token error. " + e2.toString()));
   }
   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),"Login failed! No corrispondence found into the database of users."));
}
```

This is my Test Class with the test method:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RestControllerTest {

   @InjectMocks
   RestController restController;

   @Mock
   LoginService loginService;


   @Test
   public void loginUserWithSuccessTest() throws UserNotLoggedException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
       User user = new User("BDAGPP32E08F205K", "Pippo Baudo", "ILoveSanRemoEncrypted", "conduttore");
       Optional<User> fakeUserOptional = Optional.of(user);
       when(loginService.getUserFromDbAndVerifyPassword("BDAGPP32E08F205K","ILoveSanRemo")).thenReturn(fakeUserOptional);

       String jwt = "aaaa.bbbb.cccc";
       when(loginService.createJwt(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPermission(), new Date())).thenReturn(jwt);
       //I've tested also: when(loginService.createJwt(any(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(jwt);

       //This is TRUE: assertEquals(loginService.createJwt(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPermission(), new Date()), jwt); TRUE

       //THIS IS THE METHOD BEING TESTED
       ResponseEntity serverResponse = restController.loginUser("BDAGPP32E08F205K","ILoveSanRemo");
       RestController.JsonResponseBody responseBody = restController.new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Success! User logged in." + jwt);

       assertEquals(serverResponse.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK); //TRUE
       assertThat(serverResponse.getBody(), is(responseBody)); //FALSE because jwt is NULL!!!!
   }
}
```

So, the `Mockito` rule works outside the method being tested.
Inside of it, `loginService.createJwt()` gives me a jwt null, instead of respect the value I expected from the rule I gave.
This is a very weird behavior. Why is that so? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
when(loginService.createJwt(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPermission(), new Date())).thenReturn(jwt);
```

That will almost always fail as the date will be different while mocking set-up and while actual invocation.

```
when(loginService.createJwt(any(), any(), any(), any()))
```

This is also dodgy and to vague.

I would try:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;

...

when(loginService.createJwt(eq(user.getId()), eq(user.getUsername()), eq(user.getPermission()), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(jwt);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because matching against `new Date()` wont work as this is a new object and not the one that is actually passed to the method.

You should use matchers instead:

```
when(loginService.createJwt(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPermission(),
       Matchers.any(Date.class)).thenReturn(jwt);
```

Comment: Very useful answer. Thank you! The only thing is that I've discovered that to use an Hamcrest matcher is possible only if you implement the whole line using  Hamcrest matchers.

Comment: Im glad I could help. You know I don't think I've ever mixed matchers with real expected values before. I always just assumed it would work!